# String that contains letters representing a negative number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I would like for every string that has a letter on the end make it a negative value.

```
<field> = '00000000014545p';--Varchar(15)
<field> = '00000000012645x';--Varchar(15)
<field> = '00000000012345p';--Varchar(15)
<field> = '000000004512345';--Varchar(15)

SELECT 
    SUM(CAST(<field> AS int))

FROM <table> WHERE <field> IN (38857,45678)
```

I want a return the sum of the fields.

Update: Found out that this was programmed using "over punch dibol ascii" This is why the letters are in this. p=0,q=1,r=2,s=3,t=4,u=5,v=6,w=7,x=8,y=9 
Letter means *-1

Comment: Oh my, why are you storing data this way?

Comment: Data is imported from a ISAM file.

Comment: You can stage the data and fix it before moving it to the real tables you need to work against.

Comment: In order to stage the data I still need to be able to do this. If I had Visual Studio and access I would change it in C# but I don't all has to be done in t-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really consider fixing this data before it gets into your tables, because working around bad data is cumbersome.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(col VARCHAR(15));

INSERT @x(col) VALUES
('00000000014545p'),('00000000012645n'),
('00000000012345p'),('000000004512345');

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT col, switch = CASE WHEN RIGHT(col,1) NOT LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1 END
  FROM @x
)
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, LEFT(col, 
  CASE switch WHEN 1 THEN LEN(col)-1 ELSE LEN(col) END)) 
   * CASE switch WHEN 1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
FROM x
-- WHERE ...;
```

Comment: Is there not a method of using SELECT  SUM(IIF(<field> LIKE  [^0-9],<field>,-<field>)) AS <field> FROM <table> WHERE

Comment: I cannot create update or insert on the database. Kinda makes this rough.

Comment: @oharkins: This answer doesn't create anything. The `@x` thing is a table *variable*. As far as the T-SQL language is concerned, it is *declared*, not created. Besides, it is there as a substitute for your table. Your actual query should use your real table.

Comment: (1) You don't need to create update or insert on the database. The DECLARE TABLE and INSERT here are just so you can see the sample in action, self-contained. You didn't specify the actual name of your table, either, so I gave you a sample that could work as is, which you can then adapt to your actual table by changing the table name and the column name of the query, and discarding the @x that I created. (2) No, you can't use IIF, since it was introduced to T-SQL in SQL Server 2012. It doesn't improve anything anyway, it's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

After finding out exactly what the data was I had to modify the code given from Aaron Bertrand to handle "over punch dibol ascii"

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(col VARCHAR(15));

INSERT @x(col) VALUES
('00000000014545p'),('00000000012645v'),
('00000000012345w'),('00000000012845x'),
('000000004123450'),('000000004512345');


WITH x AS 
(
SELECT 
    col, 
    switch = CASE 
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1) NOT LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1 END,
    letter = CASE
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='p' THEN 'p'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='q' THEN 'q'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='r' THEN 'r'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='s' THEN 's'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='t' THEN 't'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='u' THEN 'u'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='v' THEN 'v'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='w' THEN 'w'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='x' THEN 'x'
                WHEN RIGHT(col,1)='y' THEN 'y'
                END
FROM @x 
)
SELECT 
    SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18,2), CASE switch 
        WHEN 1 THEN 
         CASE letter 
            WHEN 'p' THEN REPLACE(col, 'p', '0') 
            WHEN 'q' THEN REPLACE(col, 'q', '1')
            WHEN 'r' THEN REPLACE(col, 'r', '2')
            WHEN 's' THEN REPLACE(col, 's', '3')
            WHEN 't' THEN REPLACE(col, 't', '4')
            WHEN 'u' THEN REPLACE(col, 'u', '5')
            WHEN 'v' THEN REPLACE(col, 'v', '6')
            WHEN 'w' THEN REPLACE(col, 'w', '7')
            WHEN 'x' THEN REPLACE(col, 'x', '8')
            WHEN 'y' THEN REPLACE(col, 'y', '9')    
         END
      ELSE col
    END)
    * CASE switch WHEN 1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)/100
FROM x;
```